Using schedule with Python & Selenium
I have a web automation script created with python and selenium.
I intend to have the script executed by task scheduler ahead of time (maybe a few seconds before) and have web driver wait until specified time to send input to the form then continue on with the rest of the script.
import schedule
import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from datetime import timedelta, date
import argparse
import time

#Handle Calendar
WebDriverWait(driver, (5)).until(
 EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='datediv']"))
)
calendar = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@id='datetxt']")

def enterdate():
    calendar.send_keys(bookingdate_day)
    return schedule.CancelJob

schedule.every().wednesday.at('17:00').do(enterdate)

while True:
 schedule.run_pending()


Please provide all imports, otherwise it is rather difficult to fully help you

Try and simply your schedule to run let us say every minute or so. so schedule.every(1).minutes to see if the schedule actually runs. Also all schedule examples I have found have a time.sleep(1) after the schedule.run_pending() call

The return statement "schedule.CancelJob" will cause the enterdate function to be executed exactly one time. If this is not your intended behavior, you should remove the return statement.

@JeremiahHerberg, I intend to have this script run maybe a few seconds ahead of the specified time using task scheduler. Web driver will then will have to wait for the time I specify to send key and continue running the rest of the script.

@Aaron Anything after the "While True" loop will never execute because nothing ever causes the loop to finish. Also, I don't see the point in using the schedule module if you are going to run the script immediately prior to when a task should execute a single time.
